# Origin of "deez nuts"

Tags: etymology, slang, jokes

I really hate to ask this one, but...

When I was a child, some thirty plus years ago, there was a popular juvenile game where you would try to trick a friend into asking a question that could be answered with the mildly obscene reply "deez nuts!" (meaning "these testicles").  Sample:

> Jokester: Did you get that CD?
>   Victim: What CD?
>   Jokester: See deez nuts!

Apparently everything old is new again --I was recently ambushed with a "deez nuts" joke by some current teenagers of my acquaintance.  Upon investigation, the old chestnut has apparently returned to currency due to a series of popular Vine videos starring a young man of amazingly unusual looks.

However, my question is this --where did the joke originally come from?  Does it date from the 80's or is it even older?  I'm fairly certain it originates somewhere within the black American urban subculture --maybe a skit on a rap album?  I've done some research, but all the citations trace back only to the recent videos, nothing any further.

Comment: Deez Nutz for President!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Berkeley High School Slang Dictionary](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Wylb8i0nTFIC&pg=PA26&dq=%22deez%20nuts%22%20slang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=G2k4VbXkFsLFgwSw1oDgDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22deez%20nuts%22%20slang&f=false) - Page 26 Rick Ayers - 2004
>
> Deez-nuts (*deez nutz*) *n*., Literally, **these testicles**.
>   Used to refer to oneself. "I'm not going to let anyone mess with
>   deez-nuts."
>   Also: Negative response to a question. “Hey, pass that
>   joint.” “Deez-nuts.”
>   [*Origin* : Hip Hop]

A **1985** reference:

> [The New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and UnconventionalThe New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional](https://books.google.ca/books?id=4YfsEgHLjboC&pg=PA570&dq=%22deez%20nuts%22%20slang&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qWw4VZLMA4vbsATh4oCAAQ&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22deez%20nuts%22%20slang&f=false) ... Eric
>   Partridge, ‎Tom Dalzell, ‎Terry Victor - 2006
>
> “I'm not going to let anyone mess with deez-nuts”— Peter Smith and Fred
>   M Barritt, *Bermewjan Vurds*. p. 18, 1985

Contradicting that is:

> Deez nuts is a phrase that originated from the song "Deeez Nuuuts" on
>   **Dr. Dre's** original album "[The Chronic](http://www.chacha.com/question/where-did-the-phrase-%27deez-nuts%27-originate)", released in **1992**.
>   (www.chacha.com)

Also, incomplete:

> Cassell's Dictionary of Slang - Page 393 Jonathon Green - 2005
>
> deez (nuts) n. [1990s+] (US Black) the testicles; the male genitals.
>   [SE these + NUTS n.2 (1)] def adj. [1970s+] (orig. US Black) perfect, excellent, first-rate.
>   [? Black pron. of SE death or abbr. SE definitive. Note **1907** cit. in Cassidy [???]

Comment: It's definitely at least 15-20 years older than that...

Comment: I see you edited some new info into this post.  I'm sure *The Chronic* gave it a new wave of popularity, but it's older than that.... The 1985 citation seems about the right date, but it doesn't give any origins.

Comment: Does there have to be an "origin"? _deez_ sounds like _these_, it's the kind of thing that kids just make up. It's like asking who invented "Duck, Duck, Goose!"

Comment: I suspect the revival is related to the popularity of the _z_ sound, and other urban mispronunciations, in hip-hop culture.

Comment: I've thought about it more, and it's possible that *The Chronic* is the right origin for its entry into mainstream culture --I could be misremembering hearing it earlier than that.  I'm going to mark this accepted.

Comment: I think it's from The Chronic album but my co-worker swears it's from a black movie before The Chronic was out. A black man is being arrested and the officer asks his name his reply is Deez Nuts or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

"Deez Nuts" may be ultimately derived from Dr. Dre's album, Chronic, or merely juvenile silliness.

But in 2015, the expression was popularized, or repopularized, by a viral meme created by  Instagram user WelvendaGreat.

According to knowyourmeme.com:

"Deez Nuts is the punchline of a conversational joke that involves asking someone a vaguely-phrased question to solicit a follow-up question in response, typically in the form of one of the five Ws, before yelling out the said phrase in an obnoxious manner. While originally introduced as a skit track on Dr. Dre's 1992 rap album Chronic, the joke saw a huge resurgence after it was featured in a short comedic sketch by Internet comedian WelvenDaGreat in early 2015."

https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/deez-nuts

Comment: The other answer has a 1985 citation, predating Dr. Dre's album.