# Questions about meanings and usage of "deez nuts"

Tags: meaning, slang

Please note, I did check the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Deez%20Nuts), and also [Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241081/origin-of-deez-nuts).

1. What was meant by the OP in https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268152/what-is-the-origin-of-best-boyfriend-ever

> “What can I say but :/ omg deez nuts.”

2. What is meant by "Deez nuts ain't loyal"?

---

Edit 8/28:

The bounty is helping, thanks to all for contributions so far.

*is used as a ribald non-sequitur* -- that is how it has been used by my pre-teen son.  Since he has echolalia (a symptom of Tourette Syndrome), there are a number of words and phrases he repeats that have no particular meaning.  Ribald I already knew.  I also knew my son uses the phrase as a non sequitur.  Is it a non sequitur for others, too?

I'd like to understand under what circumstances people say or write it, and what message or tone or *something* they are expressing when they say it.  I'm sorry if this is obvious to others.

---

More progress (8/30): Q1 -- It turns out that the OP was just writing a list of annoying modern slang expressions, so that thread is not going to help me understand under what circumstances the phrase is used, and what it is intended to express.

Maybe this will help folks understand the question: I've never seen or heard a conversation that included someone saying "These testicles", so just reminding me that that's what "deez nuts" represents doesn't answer the question.

I think it would help to read some sample situations with annotated dialogue containing "Deez nuts".  Anyone?

Or do I need to write a new question?

-- Edit upon awarding the bounty --

I still don't understand it, but now I see that there is nothing to understand.  Sigh.  Thanks, everyone.

Comment: The close votes are saying that the question does not have a correct answer, it's one where anyone can pitch in with their opinion. Really, why didn't you ask the man himself instead of placing a bounty? I might venture to say that "nuts" can also refer to insanity, if someone is *nuts* it means they are crazy or very angry (mad).

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have seen in some social media with _deez nuts_ meaning _these testicles_. Sorry if this is inappropriate but for information, I'm placing it here. If anyone wants this comment to be deleted then I will.

Comment: @CipherBot I only wanted to point out a possible interpretation of "omg deez nuts" the links the OP shared give the definition you also provided.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes I understand. Just wanted to add this information to your list of definitions as well.

Comment: it's ... madness ... that this was voted to be closed.  If you have "BEEN ON MARS" the idiom in question is a current, "hot button" contemporary news-item in the US.  It's a completely natural question for here.

Comment: "I see that there are three close votes and a down vote, but there are no comments -- what is the problem with this question?"  The problem is not with the question. The problem is - there's no other way to say it - voting on this site is **utterly bizarre**.  You get people   with -- absolutely no offence meant -- almost no knowledge of English or current English, voting on things they know nothing about, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm sure it's been said, but not explicitly as an answer: *deez nuts*, as @CipherBot says, means "these nuts" (as in testicles). The phrase comes from Dr. Dre's album *The Chronic*. To my knowledge, there is no other interpretation, and the meaning above quite clearly fits both of your example sentences.

Comment: Overheard at the [Montana Testicle Festival](http://www.legendsofamerica.com/mt-testiclefestival.html): "Deez nuts very tasty!" "Have you tried deez nuts? Spicy." "Where'd they get all deez nuts?" And so on. Context is everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) It's a parody of shallow internet comments, combining several trendy phrases in a manner meant to be reminiscent of an annoying teenager.  In order they are a wry-faced emoticon, an lolspeak abbreviation for the phrase "Oh my God!" and a reference to a popular juvenile joke, where the phrase "deez nuts," meaning "these (my) testicles" is used as a ribald non-sequitur.

2) Although literally a boast of non-fidelity, the phrase originates, as indicated by Alex, as a mash-up of a popular phrase used in several hip hop songs ("these hos ain't loyal") with the joke.

As discussed [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241081/origin-of-deez-nuts), the phrase was originally used as the punchline to a joke where the goal was to trick the victim into providing the set-up (*ex:* "Did you hear that CD?"  "What CD?"  "See deez nuts!") However, the recent return to popularity was probably as a result of this set of videos, where the phrase is used more as a *non sequitur* in ambush comedy. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcnUTyI9iJU

Answer (score 4):

"deez nuts" is an extremely well-known slang "meme" in the US, for some 10 (?) years.  It's so well-known I can't be bothered googling to copy and paste information on it.

It has particularly flared up recently and is, one could say, one of the biggest "language meme" stories in the US recently...

[image]

http://www.cbsnews.com/news/deez-nuts-is-running-for-president/

Note that the reason the question was asked here, was, someone used

## "deez nuts"

and indeed

## "omg"

and indeed the emoticon

## " :/ "

in passing, and bitterly, ***as examples of*** "annoying current slang-and-typographic forms", in the question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268152/what-is-the-origin-of-best-boyfriend-ever?noredirect=1#comment594805_268152).

---

In answer to your other question,

> What is meant by "Deez nuts ain't loyal"?

As far as I know, it simply and rather sadly means "I am not faithful," i.e., I am not sexually faithful, I am not monogamous. Note that "deez" is a rap/whatever version of "these".  (Not unlike "dat" for "that.")

---

Regarding your now third further, separate, question.  You've hit the nail on the head, "Deez Nuts" is mostly just used as a more or less content-free, silly sort of non-sequitor.  It's just a silly phrase, with silly use. You're not going to "find out" much about the usage of it. It's little different from yelling out "F--- me!" or "F--- you!" in various contexts. That's all there is to it.

Comment: perhaps **the single most famous rap album** of all time, "the chronic".  it's the main thing mentioned on the link you mention.  it is so unbelievably bizarre that this question has close votes I ... just can't be bothered.  I'm going to go to the italian language site and close questions about idioms and slang!  maybe japanese too, I can say konichiwa - I'm qualified

Comment: Once you finally get around to answering it, this is a good answer, to the only part of the question that can be answered, with some level of authority. The beginning of this answer is, *deez nuts, yo* (so I guess, maybe it is pertinent after all ;).

Comment: @JoeBlow - When you included this phrase in the other thread, were you just letting loose some random bad words, or was there any meaning associated with "deez Nuts" for you, in that context?

Comment: Hi Apparente.  Sorry if I did not clearly explain it above. As it says above, I used *examples of "annoying, current slang-and-typographic forms"*.  So, I used "deez nuts", "omg" and the emoticon as **three examples of, today's 'silly' language**..  For me, the "Best. Boyfriend. Ever." form is, let's just say bluntly, **quite silly**.    So, I was giving **some other examples** of (what I consider) "silly" language forms of today.

Comment: Further, Apparente, notice I said **"What can I say but ..."**.  And then had the three examples. That stock-phrase is (typically) an indicator that the following content is sarcastic, perhaps demeaning, or bitterly argumentative.  For example, person A might say "the Greeks have no culture!" and person B might reply sarcastically "What can I say but the Parthenon and Homer" ... you see what I mean?  I hope that explains it.

Comment: @JoeBlow - Thanks for explaining.  You were just typing a list.

Comment: Correct. It's a list. You could say it's sort of a pointless sentence, formed from three such items; it is a "parody sentence".  Cheers

Comment: Can you please vote-up the answers after all this effort :)

Comment: @JoeBlow - Okay, done, but I'm still hoping to find out in what circumstances the expression tends to get used, and what it communicates from the speaker to the listener.

Comment: Apa - I really believe it's a genuine non-sequitor, which means almost nothing.  An interjection like "imagine that" or "whoa" or "for sure".  Used either for surprise-leaning interjections or reinforcement-leaning interjections.

Comment: @JoeBlow - I found this helpful: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Deez+Nuts.  "1) A sarcastic expression used to denote annoyance or frustration [note, this definition is similar to an expression that I've read in Nero Wolfe mysteries written in the 40's]; 2) A term used when you just don't give a f___; 3) Look, my d___ and b___ are bigger than yours."  The link to that "top definition" was in the link you provided about the presidential candidate.  I noticed it on the third reading...

Comment: I'm starting to get the feeling this phrase is a little bit like "My ass", when that phrase gets overused, as for example in this definition I found on Urban Dictionary:  "used as a smart-alecky answer when lacking a good one."  //  I want to point out that the thing you called my third question ("in what circumstances the expression tends to get used, and what it communicates from the speaker to the listener") is what I wanted to know all along!  When I wrote the question, I didn't realize you were only writing a list of mindless expressions in that post I referenced.

Comment: Hi Aparente. **"I'm starting to get the feeling this phrase is a little bit like "My ass""**  Yes, it is precisely and exactly like "my ass".  Note that a large number of people have now pointed this out a large number of ties - heh!  **You've completely got it now.**  You need to **tick an answer** so the question can be closed.  I suggest Chris' is the most perfectly-phrased.

Answer (score 2):

1. Does not have an answer, the author likely misinterpreted the meme's usage
2. Deez Nuts ain't loyal is a variation on ["These hoes ain't loyal"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXRN_LkCa_o) EXPLICIT LANGUAGE WARNING, a line in a song by Chris Brown. Many people said "Deez" instead of "These", so a "Deez Nuts" Joke was inevitable.

Comment: Alex, point 1 is wrong.  Re point 2, I believe that is not in fact anything like the first usage, eg http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/deez-nuts

Comment: @Alex - If the author had misinterpreted the meme, I would still want to know what the meme means.  Can you help?